# How to automate Databricks Python call from notebook?

Tags: databricks

I am currently populating data tables in Databricks from csv files using the script below. The goal of this script is to read the csv into the existing table and match the data type of each column to the data type of the existing table (see the post here: [Error in Databricks using "copy into" SQL command to populate table from csv file (string is not converted to integer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76059128/error-in-databricks-using-copy-into-sql-command-to-populate-table-from-csv-fil)).

I'd like to automate this process such that a person doesn't need to open up the notebook and run the script. How do I automate this?

If I could do this is SQL I could call the SQL script programmatically.

Is there a Databricks REST API call that can execute a Python script?

Is there another way this can be automated?

```
%python
tables = [
'care_site',
]

target_db = 'demo_cdm'
data_path = '/FileStore/tables/prod/ohdsi/demo_cdm/'

for t in tables:
  tgt_t = t.lower()
  df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM {db}.{table}'.format(db=target_db, table=tgt_t))
  spark.read.options(delimiter=",", header="True", dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd")\
          .schema(df.schema)\
          .csv(data_path + t + '/' + t + '.csv')\
          .write.format('delta')\
          .insertInto(target_db + '.' + tgt_t.lower(), overwrite=True)
  spark.sql('REFRESH TABLE {db}.{table}'.format(db=target_db, table=tgt_t))
```

Comment: Take a look at Workflows

Comment: It looks like Workflows requires the existence of the Notebook.  I believe there is a way to programmatically upload a Notebook, so that's good.  Is there a way to programmatically execute a Notebook remotely (e.g. through a REST API call)?

Comment: Ofc: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs.html#jobsjobsservicesubmitrun